# Replace a "Map<UUID, String>" interface for a simpler "IMap"

Tags: java, interface

I have some code that use a Map like this:

```
Map<UUID, String> object = new Hashmap<UUID, String>();
```

And it works fine. But, as I have to use this same definition in other parts of the code, I wrote this interface:

```
interface IMap extends Map<UUID, String>{
}
```

The idea is that is simpler to write `IMap` than `Map<UUID, String>`.

Anyway, this does not work:

```
IMap object = new HashMap<UUID, String>();
```

The error message from the compiler is:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from HashMap<UUID,String> to IMap
```

I think that, as `IMap` extends `Map<UUID, String>`, that would work, but no. Is there a way to do that replacement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not work because `HashMap` does not implement your `IMap` interface - so you cannot assign a `HashMap` to a variable of type `IMap`.

You could make a class (not an interface) that extends `HashMap`:

```
class XMap extends HashMap<UUID, String> { }

XMap map = new XMap();
```

(Personally I don't like to misuse inheritance just to just give something a more convenient name, but that might be a matter of opinion - and Java doesn't have another mechanism to do this).

Answer (score 1):

Type inference does not work is such a way. It does not matter if the `IMap` extends `Map`.

**If the concrete implementation does not implement `IMap` interface (and `java.util.collection.HashMap` does not) you simply cannot assign it to the `IMap` interface.**

Comment: I understand... that can't be done with interfaces, but is there another way to do the same, to use `IMap` just an equivalent to `Map<UUID, String>`?

Comment: Using generics, but we would need deeper code samples.